# React.js transpile issue. Babel build commands not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, frontend, babeljs

I have been following the react: up and running book by stoyan stephanov. Chapter 5. I am stuck at the command:

babel --presets react,es2015 js/source -d js/build

result: es2015 does not exist.

But when I try:
babel --presets react js/source -d js/build

it works as expected in the book.

And then I write:
babel --presets react,es2015 js/source -d js/build

result: Syntax error at app.js. Unexpected token before h1 tag.

**App.js code**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Logo from './components/Logo';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>
    Welcome to the  app!
  </h1>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

All optional presets must be installed manually, as far as I know:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

*P.S. [Here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) are some additional data on issue.*

Comment: You'd want to --saveDev in this instance as it's purely a dev tool to transpile back to old skool JS.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response fellows. I tried the command mentioned by @ankhzet but later tried the command: babel --presets react,es2015 js/source -d js/build. Unfortunately the same message. Am i missing something?

Comment: @ZahirJunejo, only suggestion I can give, try reverse order for presets: `babel --presets es2015,react js/source -d js/build`. The order in which transformations are applied is actually important when `.babelrc` is used, maybe it's also applies to cli